# Describing props with propTypes that come from a Higher order component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) (and it's package for react) and have a class component that uses `withTranslation()`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // some default values are set here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // some http requests are happening here
  }

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      <h1>{t('pageHome:title')}</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(Home);
```

I am also using [airbnb: javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) and I get on this line the following "error":

> ESLint: `t` is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

because `t` is available from `withTranslation()` HOC added to `Home` component.

Is that the right approach, or something can tell the linter that this prop is defined in HOC? Or am I missing completely the point of those prop types?

```
Home.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Im 100% recommending, start with typescript as soon as possible, much better than any proptypes, than there is no need to use them, it has better types and much better linting, autocomplete ...

Comment: Does it work then? sometimes ignoring the ESLint errors are the best solution :)

Comment: @Tonoslav: thank you for the recommendation. I am currently exploring the javascript world. Typescript is on my to-do list already. Yes, Amir, if I add the `Home.propTypes` object as described in the question, the linter's error disappears.

Comment: I'm 100% disagreeing. Typescript is good but also a lot more involved to setup and manage. Whilst I mostly use Typescript I have a much easier time managing code with React PropTypes and ultimately I mostly use Typescript for just prop types and function argument types so there is very little gain for me aside from files which are pure JS.

Comment: @Alex if you cannot see gain, you are using it wrong, I had the same view like year or 2 ago, now I cannot imagine javascript without it

Comment: I've used it for the last 6 years and its always a pain to setup the way I want. The most important type checking in React are the props anyway as these are the real interface. I also hate the separation its causing in the JS community, people have learned nothing from JQuery and CoffeeScript. Supersets are great when there is no native equivalent, this is not the case with ES6 anymore aside from static types where it still serves a purpose.